# Vertically Align the cells of UICollectionView to top in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

How do I vertically align the cells of my uicollectionview to the top in swift?

I've seen people subclassing them in objective-c but i haven't found one answer in swift.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried doing the equivalent of your objective c example using Swift?

Comment: I don't really understand too much of it, I've never created an extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using FSQCollectionView which was perfect for my needs.

The project is availble here :

https://github.com/foursquare/FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout

And the two methods needed were:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout!, attributesForSectionAtIndex sectionIndex: Int) -> FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayoutSectionAttributes! {

    return FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayoutSectionAttributes.withHorizontalAlignment(FSQCollectionViewHorizontalAlignment.Center, verticalAlignment: FSQCollectionViewVerticalAlignment.Top)
}
```

and

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout!, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, remainingLineSpace: CGFloat) -> CGSize {

        return CGSizeMake(100, 100)
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to implement this method to my project. I added `.m` and `.h` files properly. I created method you told about above. But there is problem these method that i got in the project, doesn't work. I added `print(_:)` to test it, and it printed nothing. It has been long time that you had wroten this answer, but any help will make me appreciated.

Comment: What was the solution? I'm not hitting these methods with break points. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I used the library provided but I think a new answer is warranted in that the last one was pretty incomplete for those not 100% familiar with how custom layouts work with UICollectionViews.

Step 1 - import the two files `FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout.h` and `FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout.m` (or put `pod 'FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout'` in your podfile and run `pod install`)

Step 2 - Add them to your bridging header because you're probably using Swift. (Not necessary if you imported as a pod)

Step 3 - In your storyboard, change the "Layout" attribute in Attributes inspector to Custom, then add your custom class (FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout) in that field.

Step 4 - Add the delegate methods to your ViewController and edit properties as needed. Also make sure to `import FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout` at the top of your ViewController class.